# How to add postmeta value with WP API/JS?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to add a postmeta value by using JS only in WordPress? For example by using the Wordpress API? I need to add some postmeta values for media.

If it is possible, how to achieve it?

The reason I want to do it is because I want to add "Extra info" field just underneath `Description` of media. See the image:

[image]

That `Extra info` is added by JS as well since, as far as I know, there is no hook I can use to put it underneath `Description` like this.
Using `attachment_fields_to_edit` is not acceptable since it adds fields under `Uploaded by` (it just must be underneath `Description` and above `Uploaded by`...).

For that reason I see JS as only solution. When user edits the field the JS would save the contents of `Extra info`.

Of course, I am open for non-JS solutions if they do the job.

Comment: Any particular reason for the requirement of "*JS only*"? Can you elaborate on the use case a bit more?

Comment: You could send an AJAX request to the [/wp/v2/posts/<id> endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#update-a-post) and include the meta field(s) you wish to add/update. Note that you'll need to be authenticated first or else the REST API will reject your request for security reasons.

Comment: @esqew I edited the question and added more details.

Comment: @cabrerahector, thanks for advice, I'll try that.

Comment: You know, you could also use jQuery's [after()](https://api.jquery.com/after/) function to move your custom "Extra Info" field right below the "Description" field and so using the `attachment_fields_to_edit` hook wouldn't be an issue anymore.

Comment: @cabrerahector I thought about that, but there is a catch. Fields above "Uploaded by" are actually updated via WP JS. And for fields underneath (fields that can be added with attachment_fields_to_edit) - those fields are inside separate `<form>` so I assume they are saved in a different way (not with JS). If I use .after() the field will no longer be inside that from. For some reason, WP has some inconsistency there (even the markup of fields above and beneath is different, even though fields look the same).